# Issue with alignment of page

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been struggling for several hours about this problem, although it seems ridiculous I cant fix it somehow.

So this is the webpage draft, http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/test.html

If you click on the Bio link, you will notice that the topbar menu on the Biography.html is moving slightly to the right.

How can we fix that? Any ideas?

p.s I have noticed that If I have the same picture in biography.html as in test.html there is no problem, the topbar remains in the saim position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This forces a scrollbar on the right hand side

Answer (score 0):

That's because your first page has a scroll bar and the bio page doesn't. You can force a scrollbar to always show up which can be annoying but consistent, or use absolute positioning to have the content always appear in a specific location, albeit probably not centered.

Answer (score 0):

The content on the first page is going below your screen, meaning you will have to scroll. This isn't the same for the bio page, hence the inconsistencies, either add more content, set overflow-y to scroll or just ignore it (as users will)